# How to access key value from AWS Key Management Service in data bricks

Tags: amazon-kms, key-management, aws-databricks

I am creating a solution in AWS data bricks and wanted to access the userID and password of RDS from AWS KMS.

Anyone has created this scenario please help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're doing here?  KMS is used to manage encryption keys not RDS credentials.  I'm also unclear how this relates to RDS anyway.

Comment: i want to put DB credentials Like UserName Password in KMS and then i'll access those credentials in my databricks notebook. so for securing the credential i'll use KMS as we did in Azure key vault

Answer (score 0):

KMS is NOT the correct service for storing DB credentials.  In AWS you should use Secrets Manager or Systems Manager Parameter Store for this.

[Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html)

Comment: okay then how do we communicate with data bricks to provide secrets from the secret manager